# Angular 1: multiple conditions with multiple conditions OR how to exclude conditions if other conditions are true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Right now I have created an extra span to hold one condition.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, resultLinks) in resultGroup.resultLinks">
    <div ng-if="key < 4 || viewMore" ng-repeat="(subKey, linksWrap) in resultLinks.linksWrap">
        <span ng-if="wWidth > 568 || subKey == 0" ng-repeat="links in linksWrap.links">
                {{links.linkName}}
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How would you change it so that all the conditions are in one div. Ie: ng-if="(key < 4 || viewMore) || (wWidth > 568 || subKey == 0)" (something like this, but not quite). Like is it possible to somehow exclude one condition if another is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
(key < 4 || viewMore) && (wWidth > 568 || subKey == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to somehow exclude one condition if another is true?

That is exactly what OR (`||`) operator is doing. If `(key < 4 || viewMore)` is `true` it will not go further, `(wWidth > 568 || subKey == 0)` will not execute.

This should work:

```
    <div ng-if="(key < 4 || viewMore) || (wWidth > 568 || subKey == 0)" ng-repeat="(subKey, linksWrap) in resultLinks.linksWrap">
        <span ng-repeat="links in linksWrap.links">
               {{links.linkName}}
        </span>
    </div>
```

As you can see it looks pretty ugly. I would move logic out of template:

```
<div ng-if="isVisible(key, subKey)"... >
```

Somewhere in your controller:

```
$scope.isVisible = function(key, subKey){  
    return (key < 4 || $scope.viewMore) || ($scope.wWidth > 568 || subKey == 0)
}
```

Comment: I was missing the  && instead of ||

Comment: Just as an OT. Why is it ugly in DOM? I see no reason why I should split the code into 2 places when I can keep it in one, should I?

Comment: uglyness is very subjective :) Some people keep their code in `<script>` tags.